# urdf_to_collada undefined reference to vtable for Assimp::IOSystem

Tags: ros, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on getting ROS and the robot variant packages setup on an armhf port of Ubuntu. About 40 of the 100 robot variant packages have built just fine, however I'm having trouble with the collada_urdf package.

More specifically, when it is trying to link the urdf_to_collada executable the linker is complaining that collada_urdf.so has an unresolved dependency for IOSystem's vtable. With Assimp being a system package, I'm not sure how to go about resolving this problem.

I've tried reordering the libraries in urdf_to_collada's link.txt file to no avail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48084/urdf_to_collada-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-assimp::iosystem/) by [GIBurrito](https://answers.ros.org/users/3300/giburrito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-14**:
This bug has been ticketed here: https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/12

**Comment by [mikealger](https://answers.ros.org/users/20000/mikealger/) on 2014-08-14**:
This issue also appears while compiling indigo on an odroid-xu using the standard ubuntu 14.04 image, applying the patch from bit-pirate seems to fix this,  hopefully this saves someone else a couple hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this question is old, but I think I found the answer :)

The problem is that it does not detect the correct assimp version. vi into src/collada_urdf/src/collada_urdf.cpp and write #define IS_ASSIMP3 at the top of the file. Also make sure you actually have assimp3 installed. You can download the source [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/assimp/files/assimp-3.0)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-14**:
I was able to compile collada_urdf from source without any changes (but had to assimp3 as suggested). Thanks for the tip!

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-06-11**:
I opened an new issue here: https://github.com/ros/collada_urdf/issues/9
The other issues are closed which makes them hard to find

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like I hit the same problem again:-( With libassimp3 on Ubuntu 13.10 (armhf). With a different g++ on 13.04 (x64), my little test source seems to compile as expected:-(

http://pastie.org/8665639

---

Originally posted by [mw46d](https://answers.ros.org/users/11221/mw46d/) with karma: 21 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it for armhf (Raspberrypi)  adding to the robot_model/collada_urdf/src/collada_urdf.cpp file the next code:

```
 #ifdef __arm__                 // fix for ARM build
 #include 
 bool Assimp::IOSystem::ComparePaths(const char *p1, const char *p2) const
 {
    return !::strcasecmp(p1, p2);
 }
 #  endif
```

This solution is inspired in this other one: http://answers.ros.org/question/52098/unable-to-compile-rviz-on-ubuntu-armhf/

But in that case is solved specifically for the rviz. I think that adding this code in this file a more much general solution is provided.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2015-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tormod Haugene](https://answers.ros.org/users/23774/tormod-haugene/) on 2016-03-12**:
I found this same solution in the following google group, made as a patch file.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ros-sig-embedded/26XlDtZhyNs/OexZAx6BCBcJ